# Increment (++) a dereferenced pointer in a macro --> result is +2 instead of +1

Tags: pointers, macros, increment

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MIN(x, y) ((x) <= (y) ? (x) : (y))

int main ()
{
int x=5, y=0, least;
int *p;
p = &y;
least = MIN((*p)++, x);
printf("y=%d", y);
printf("\nleast=%d", least);
return 0;
}
```

I would expect the following result:
    `y=1`
    `least=1`
but instead `y=2`.
Can somebody explain why `y` is now `2` and not `1`. I suppose that it is because some double incrementation, but I do not understand the mechanism behind it.
Thanks.

Comment: This is a perfect illustration of why one should prefer inline functions to macros.

Answer (score 1):

Preprocessor macros work by text substitution. So your line:

```
least = MIN((*p)++, x);
```

gets expanded to

```
least = (((*p)++) <= (x) ? ((*p)++) : (x));
```

The double-increment is clear.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are using a macro. Since you are passing the dereferenced pointer plus the increment through the macro, the macro then puts the dereferenced pointer and the increment operation in each place y shows up in your macro. Since y shows up twice in your macro, the increment operator happens two times.

If you do the increment before you call the macro y should only be 1.